# Can I use Google Mobile Vision API in PyCharm?

Tags: android, python, api

I am exploring the APIs provided by `Google`. Firstly, I was experimenting with `Google Cloud Vision API` with Python in PyCharm in order to try to perform Optical Character Recognition with various texts.

So I wrote a basic program in Python in PyCharm which was calling this API, I gave to it as an input an image which included text e.g. the `image/photo` of an ice-cream bucket and then takes the text written on this bucket as an output.

Now I want to test the barcode scanner of `Google Mobile Vision API`. So ideally I would like to call the `Google Mobile Vision API` in a python program in PyCharm which calls this API, give as an input an `image/photo` of a barcode and take as an output the details saved in this barcode.

My question is if this can be (easily) done with `PyCharm` or if I should download Android Studio to do this simple task?

In other words, can I call easily a mobile API in an IDE which is not for mobile app development like Android Studio but in an IDE for desktop applications like Pycharm?

It may be a very basic question but I do not know if I missing something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobile vision API is designed only for Android and iOS. As far as I know, Pycharm does not work well with Java, so I would say that you would have to create an Android/iOS project in order to test it (It would be a lot harder trying to make it work with python than simply installing Android studio and cloning a mock project).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, this is what I was thinking but I was wondering if I am missing something obvious. However just to clarify something, you are saying that 'Pycharm does not work well with Java' but even if Pycharm was working well with Java I think that it would be also very difficult to do this on Pycharm because it is an IDE which is very different from mobile app development IDEs like Android Studio. So my point is that this more a matter of IDE and not a matter of programming language. Am I right?

Comment: IDE and programming languages are some abstractions that make our lives easier. With enough time you will be able to create an Android app using only Notepad, but it will not worth the time. As conclusion, the Vision API could work with python if you invest a lot of time  in it, but it will not be worth it because it was designed for Android/iOS only.

Comment: Yes, for sure. I am just saying exactly that even if I could write directly with Java in PyCharm then again it would take way more time than developing this basic program in Android Studio. In this way, I claim that this is more a matter of IDE's (like you said that it 'will be able to create an Android app using only Notepad, but it will not worth the time') and not exactly on programming languages (as you could write Java on Notepad but you should write so much things in comparison with an IDE like Android Studio).

Comment: The important thing is that you should install AndroidStudio or InteliJ and start working there.If you will check the docs for Vision API you'll find project from github that can be cloned and tested. Don't even bother to think at trying to make it work with Python because it's not worth it.

Comment: Haha, yes ok I agree and thank you for your help. I just wanted to understand theoretically why exactly it is not worth it to write on PyCharm and Python (and if it is more a matter of IDE or of programming language).